# Ionic 2: use HtmlInfoWindow in native cordova-plugin-googlemaps

Tags: cordova, google-maps, ionic2, google-maps-markers, cordova-plugins

I use cordova-plugin-googlemaps in my app.
https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/google-maps/

My code:

```
  loadMap() {

    var element: HTMLElement = document.getElementById('map');
    var map: GoogleMap = this.googleMaps.create(element);
    map.one(GoogleMapsEvent.MAP_READY).then(() => {

      var ionic: LatLng = new LatLng(50.5279314,30.2317489);

      var position: CameraPosition = {
        target: ionic,
        zoom: 10,
      };
      map.moveCamera(position);

      var htmlInfoWindow = new HtmlInfoWindow();
      htmlInfoWindow.setContent('<div>Test</div>');

      map.addMarker({
        position: new LatLng(50.5279314,30.2317489),
      }).then((marker: Marker) => {
        marker.on(GoogleMapsEvent.MARKER_CLICK).subscribe(() => {
          htmlInfoWindow.open(marker);
        });
      });

    });

  }
```

When I try to open HtmlInfoWindow, i get errors. Help, please:

> console.error: Unhandled Promise rejection: marker.bindTo is not a
>   function. (In  'marker.bindTo("infoWindowAnchor", self)',
>   'marker.bindTo' is undefined) ; Zone:  ; Task: null ;  Value: 
>   [object Object]
>   http://192.168.0.104:8102/plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/HtmlInfoWindow.js:233:22
>   fromLatLngToPoint@http://192.168.0.104:8102/plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/Map.js:620:26  open@http://192.168.0.104:8102/plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/HtmlInfoWindow.js:229:26
>   http://192.168.0.104:8102/build/vendor.js:56416:25
>   t@http://192.168.0.104:8102/build/polyfills.js:3:15045 
>   tryNativePromise@http://192.168.0.104:8102/build/vendor.js:56415:31 
>   http://192.168.0.104:8102/build/main.js:85:40 
>   __tryOrUnsub@http://192.168.0.104:8102/build/vendor.js:31152:20  next@http://192.168.0.104:8102/build/vendor.js:31099:34 
>   _next@http://192.168.0.104:8102/build/vendor.js:31039:30  next@http://192.168.0.104:8102/build/vendor.js:31003:23 
>   listener@http://192.168.0.104:8102/plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/BaseClass.js:60:21  dispatchEvent@[native code] 
>   trigger@http://192.168.0.104:8102/plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/BaseClass.js:43:27 
>   _onMarkerEvent@http://192.168.0.104:8102/plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/Map.js:982:23  nativeCallback@http://192.168.0.104:8102/plugins/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/www/googlemaps-cdv-plugin.js:313:32
>   nativeCallback@[native code] dispatchEvent@[native code] 
>   fireDocumentEvent@http://192.168.0.104:8102/cordova.js:235:35 global
>   code@http://192.168.0.104:8102/:1:37

Comment: See this [link](https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps-doc/tree/master/v2.0.0/class/HtmlInfoWindow/newHtmlInfoWindow)

Comment: I saw this link, but it does not help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems the ionic team forgot to implement the `bindTo` method of BaseClass.

I sent a pull request. Should work.

https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-native/pull/1815

Comment: I have been still waiting the ionic team merge the pull request for some reason.

Comment: The pull request has been accepted. Please reinstall the plugin.

Comment: Hi @wf9a5m75, I updated my plugin today but it is still not working. When i call `htmlInfoWindow.open(marker);` it throw an error: `TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'getId'`

Comment: Please report at the issue list of the github repository. Then I will help you. This is not good place to follow up your issue. https://github.com/mapsplugin/cordova-plugin-googlemaps/issues

Comment: The bug was fixed in the @ionic-native/core and @ionic-native/google-maps ver4.2.0

Please reinstall these two packages.

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/core
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@ionic-native/google-maps